# Is it bad practice to put other items besides module names in a package's __all__ variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm creating a digital version of the "triangle peg game" (the one commonly found at Cracker Barrel) using Python 3.6.0. I'm including a module called "stats" that allows the game to analyze all possible playthroughs, so that when the player presses the help button, it will give him the best possible move.

While this project is primarily an application, I want to have the source code available too, so that others can read it or use it if they want. To that end (and for my use in creating the game), I've included two graphics classes. The first, using turtle, will be used when someone actually plays the game, and the second, using ASCII to increase speed and efficiency, can be used for stats testing. I've created a subpackage called "graphics", and each class is in its own module inside "graphics". I decided, after much thought, to put the base class in the __init__ module. Also, since I want its __all__ variable to include everything useful to someone using the source code, I put the name of the base class in it.

Here's the __init__ module:

```
"""Initializes the 'graphics' subpackage."""

__all__ = ["Graphics", "ascii_", "turtle_"]

class Graphics:
    """Base class for all graphics classes.

    instance attributes
    -------------------
    '_game' -- the instance of 'game.Game' that the object is assigned to.
    This attribute is not assigned until the game is begun.
    """

    def _construct(self):
        """Constructs the graphics for the game."""
        pass

    def _update(self):
        """Updates the graphics when a move is made."""
        pass

    # Move back to ASCIIGraphics if not necessary for other graphics
    # classes.
    def _erase(self):
        """Updates the graphics when a move is undone."""
        pass

    def _reset(self):
        """Resets the graphics when the game is restarted."""
        pass
```

Should a package's __all__ variable exclusively contain module names, or can it contain the names of base classes/package-level globals defined in __init__ as well?

P.S.: I'm very much aware that "from [package|module] import *" is frowned upon by many, and I've already looked into whether base classes should be defined in __init__. That being said, this is the first time I've ever made a package in Python, and if you wish to give me advice as well as answer my question, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Including classes -- as you're doing here -- is entirely appropriate. Anything that's intended for to be part of your module's external interface should be listed.

Comment: If the user will likely want it when they do `from foo import *` then it should probably be listed in `__all__`.